# Is there a way to break from a range() function at a specific value?

Tags: python, range, break

I am new to programming in python and am trying to design a calendar that starts the month depending on the selected start day.
However, I don't know how to stop the print once the number of days has been exceeded(e.g breaks at days=31 when month=="January")
The printed values must be right-aligned additionally.
Here is how I first approached it:

```
month=input("Enter the month: ")

if month=="January" or month=="March" or month=="May" or month=="July" or month=="August" or month=="October" or month=="December":
    days=31
else:
    days=30
if month=="February":
    days=28
Start_day=input("Enter the start day: ")
print(month)
print("Mo","Tu","We","Th","Fr","Sa","Su")
if Start_day == "Monday":
    i=1
if Start_day == "Tuesday":
    i=0
if Start_day == "Wednesday":
    i=-1
if Start_day == "Thursday":
    i=-2
if Start_day == "Friday" :
    i=-3
if Start_day == "Saturday":
    i=-4
if Start_day == "Sunday":
    i=-5

j=1
for j in range(i,days,7):
    print(str(j).rjust(2," "),str(j+1).rjust(2," "),str(j+2).rjust(2," "),str(j+3).rjust(2," "),str(j+4).rjust(2," "),str(j+5).rjust(2," "),str(j+6).rjust(2," "))
```

Comment: Just to note (and not a direct answer): unless you're doing this as a learning experiment - you'll find the [`calendar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html) module very useful here

Comment: As an aside, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 0):

Before you print after your for loop just have an **if statement** to check for your condition and before you print add a break statement.
Something like:

```
if statement:
   break
```

Answer (score 0):

You could encode it instead as

```
j=1
for j in range(i,days,7):
  for i in range(0,7):
    if j+i>days: break
    print(str(j+i).rjust(2," "),end=' ')
  print('')
```

This would be called "breaking out of a loop" rather than "breaking from a range function." There is no way to "break from a range function."

Answer (score 0):

Can I suggest overhauling this a bit to be more efficient? You can use dicts and define a custom function to handle the date formatting to prevent some repetition.

To answer your question, you can evaluate the date number during the final loop:

```py
for j in range(i,days,7):
    # add to j value via range() and adjust()
    # (defined above) to prevent repetition
    for k in range(7):
        if j + k > 0 and j + k <= days:
            print(adjust(j + k), end = ' ') # don't print new line
        else:
            # print spaces if the number is <1 or >days
            print('   ', end = '')
    # print new line for a new week
    print('\n', end = '')
```

Full example:

```py
# function to format dates later
def adjust(val):
    return str(val).rjust(2," ")

# get inputs
month=input("Enter the month: ")
start_day=input("Enter the start day: ")

# map months to days in a dict
month_to_days={"january":31,
               "march":31,
               "may":31,
               "july":31,
               "august":31,
               "october":31,
               "december":31,
               "february":28,
               "april":30,
               "june":30,
               "september":30,
               "october":30
               }
# map weekdays to int
days_to_int={"monday":1,
             "tuesday":0,
             "wednesday":-1,
             "thursday":-2,
             "friday":-3,
             "saturday":-4,
             "sunday":-5
             }

# get the day amount based on the entry, ignoring case
days=month_to_days[month.lower()]
# get the int based on the entry, ignoring case
i=days_to_int[start_day.lower()]

# print month and day headers
print(month)
print("Mo","Tu","We","Th","Fr","Sa","Su")

for j in range(i,days,7):
    # add to j value via range() and adjust()
    # (defined above) to prevent repetition
    for k in range(7):
        if j + k > 0 and j + k <= days:
            print(adjust(j + k), end = ' ') # don't print new line
        else:
            # print spaces if the number is <1 or >days
            print('   ', end = '')
    # print new line for a new week
    print('\n', end = '')
```

Output:

```py
Enter the month: january
Enter the start day: monday
january
Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7 
 8  9 10 11 12 13 14 
15 16 17 18 19 20 21 
22 23 24 25 26 27 28 
29 30 31             
>>> 
Enter the month: june
Enter the start day: wednesday
june
Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su
       1  2  3  4  5 
 6  7  8  9 10 11 12 
13 14 15 16 17 18 19 
20 21 22 23 24 25 26 
27 28 29 30
```

Comment: Thank you kindly for your method, it is very helpful in understanding. Just to be clear, when you write j + k, the interpreter doesn't evaluate the the numerical value of the the summation of the two values? Does it rather return the value existing at that point in the range?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question exactly, but you're correct that the interpreter evaluates the sum of the two placeholders, j and k, at their respective steps as it cycles through the ranges.